# Options in command line of Java jar file

Tags: java, input, nullpointerexception, apache-commons-cli, stringreader

I tried to search around but see no appropriate document showing how to do so I post this.

I want to call a function in my jar file to process a string given in command line such as:

```
java -jar myFile.jar -s "This is the string I want to process"
```

The used code is as follows:

```
Option inputStringOpt = new Option("s", "Input string");
options.addOption(inputStringOpt);
try {
     CommandLine commandLine = commandLineParser.parse(options, args);
     String inputString = commandLine.getOptionValue("s");
     //Call the required function
     someFunction(inputString);
}
catch (ParseException e) {
    System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
}
```

However, the inputString is always null. How can I read the desired string?

For more information, it throws out a NullPointerException with StringReader.

Thanks.

Comment: Does the parameter show up in `args`?

Comment: Where do the classes `Option` and `CommandLine` come from, some library? They are not standard Java API classes.

Comment: Yes they come from library and I included them in the jar file.

Comment: Which library? If you want help with your question, then include all the relevant information.

Comment: @Jesper They are from commons-cli

Answer (score 1):

Your first line should be:

```
Option inputStringOpt = new Option("s", true, "Input string");
```

Comment: Does the "true" option mean it is mandatory to provide the string?

Comment: @Hoai it means that the "s" option has an argument

Comment: @MauricePerry How do you know this? He didn't even tell us where class `Option` comes from and what its API is.

Comment: @Jesper Yes, he did, in the comment below its post. Its comming from common-cli.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks a ton @MauricePerry. Voted!